# Google map will not display

Tags: google-maps

I have been struggling for awhile to get a google map to display. I have searched many forums and sites but have not found anything helpful as of yet. I am using Bootstrap. I downloaded a template with a map in in which works perfectly and am using the code from this to create my own map, for whatever reason it does not display on my site.

See link below for code:

https://jsfiddle.net/saleenm99/s5wu5v1m/

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: [Your fiddle works if you configure it correctly (no wrap in `<head>`) and include the API script](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s5wu5v1m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your code below you can see your code i have commented the image con reference because i haven't this. 
I moved the listerner on window load to the bottom (is better, i this way all the js code i loaded) 
the i  have inserted your script in a simple html wrapper

PS I haven't used your css
but it work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple click event</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="map" ></div>
  <script>

    function init() {
        // Basic options for a simple Google Map
        // For more options see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
        var mapOptions = {
            // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
            zoom: 15,

            // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400), // New York

            // Disables the default Google Maps UI components
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            scrollwheel: true,
            draggable: false,

            // How you would like to style the map. 
            // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
            styles: [{
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 17
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 20
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 17
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 29
                }, {
                    "weight": 0.2
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 18
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.local",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 16
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 21
                }]
            }, {
                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "on"
                }, {
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 16
                }]
            }, {
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [{
                    "saturation": 36
                }, {
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 40
                }]
            }, {
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{
                    "visibility": "off"
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 19
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 20
                }]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [{
                    "color": "#000000"
                }, {
                    "lightness": 17
                }, {
                    "weight": 1.2
                }]
            }]
        };

        // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map 
        // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
        var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

        // Create the Google Map using out element and options defined above
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

        // Custom Map Marker Icon - Customize the map-marker.png file to customize your icon
        //var image = 'img/map-marker.png';
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400);
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            //icon: image
        });
    }


    // Google Maps Scripts
    // When the window has finished loading create our google map below
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help. It appears I wasn't properly references the JS file.